# Unable to create elastic Beanstalk environment with RDS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create new ELB environment with existing VPC. But I am unable to create environment with following errors:

ERROR   Creating security group named: sg-5xxxxxxx failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled

ERROR   Creating EIP:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed. Reason: Resource creation cancelled.

ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-webxxxxxx-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBEIP, AWSEBSecurityGroup, AWSEBRDSDBSubnetGroup].

Note :I still didn't cross the Elastic Ip's limit. When i configure subnet for RDS in two regions they were automatically reset to single region only while creating evironment

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Additional logs :                                                                                         
 ERROR Failed to pull logs for environment instances. Reason: Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Code:ValidationError, Message:Resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup does not exist for stack awseb-e-websxxxx-stack, Class:com.amazon.aws.mac.connectors.awsservice.cloudformation.exceptions.CfnStackResourceNotFoundException
ERROR Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup does not exist for stack awseb-e-webscxxxx-stack

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now. Limit is not reached either. Can you post an update if you find an answer elsewhere?

Comment: @gyc you found the solution?

Comment: I switched projects so I don't remember at all sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I was also having issues adding database via elastic beanstalk ui after initially creating an application using the command line interface. Turns out I had messed up my IAM (AWS Services > Security, Identity, Compliance > IAM) roles setup when I first created the account. This account was missing the role AWSServiceRoleForRDS. Once I created one, I was able to successfully configure a database for the new application.

Comment: I am the using the root account for this operation which has full access and yes AWSServiceRoleForRDS is already added