# Deploy Ruby on Rails 5 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to deploy a Ruby on Rails application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the aws cli and the elasticbeanstalk cli installed via homebrew.

I've created my application in Elastic Beanstalk via the `eb init` command and then using the following command to attempt to build my production environment

```
eb create production -db -db.engine postgres
```

This command succeeds in building some of the resources required, but fails on the second security group it tries to build, the one which is required for the RDS instance (postgresql).  The output from the failure is as follows:

```
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-060304732879 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-6df63b27
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-v-AWSEBLoa-SNYOVF7XI1O
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-vfpiydbe4p-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-7CUYEFRLYW20
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-vfpiydbe4p-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-PBAKQ91A7F1C
ERROR: Stack named 'awseb-e-vfpiydbe4p-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup].
ERROR: Creating RDS database security group named: awseb-e-vfpiydbe4p-stack-awsebrdsdbsecuritygroup-1er5fh5espelw failed Reason: Either the resource does not exist, or you do not have the required permissions.
INFO: Launched environment: production. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  I've double checked (and also reset) my AWS credentials and ensured that the one and only use I have set up in my IAM console is set to `AdministratorAccess` and I'm using the AWS Access and Secret Key set up for that user.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem, although it is not obvious, might be that your RDS got created with a different security group than your environment. Can you retry as `eb create -db.engine postgres -vpc` and ensure that you put the RDS and the environment in the security in the same VPC and subnets? In the  process, you will be asked to provide security group names. Pick an existing security group from the security groups page in the region for this. I think this might work.

Comment: As an aside, it is also worth mentioning that you should not use the approach of creating an RDS with your environment this way as environments take the associated RDS down with them. To work with RDSs in the context of Beanstalk, follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html)

Comment: I ran into the same issue and this answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51470042/1351770